# How can I display the results of a form login to an internal webpage with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and I am currently reading modern Javascript. It's not much help. How can I display the results of a form login to an internal webpage with javascript? I have everything set except I think my conditionals are messed up and I'm just confused. I want to get the info from my login.html page to display on myaccount.html page. How can i accomplish this? I tried jsfiddle and others as well as searching Stackoverflow.

login.html

```
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="960.css"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.js" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<form action="myaccount.html" method="post" id="myaccount">
     <fieldset>
        <legend>Login</legend>
        <div><label for="email">Email:</label>
   <input type="email" name="email"id="email" required></div><br>
        <div><label for="password">Password:</label>
   <input type="password" name="password" id="Pword" required></div><br>
        <div><label for="submit"></label>
   <input type="submit" value="Login &rarr;" id="submit"></div>

     </fieldset>
</form>
<script src="login.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

myaccount.html

```
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Account</title>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="960.css"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.js"/>

</head>
<body>

<form action="myaccount.html" method="post">
      <div><label for="result">Result:</label>
   <input type="" name="result" id="result"></div>
</form>
<script src="login.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
function empwd() {
    'use strict';

    var nameEmail = '';


    var email = document.getElementById('email').value = output;
    var password = document.getElementById('Pword').value = output;
    //var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('email').value));
    //var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('Pword').value));

    empwd = email + ', ' + Pword;

    if (email != example@gmail.com || (admin@whatever.com)) {
        email = 'Please enter a valid email.';
    } else {
        email = 'Please enter your password.';
    }
    if (Pword != 1234567 || (LogMeIn)) {
        password = 'Please try again';
    } else {
        password = 'Thank you';
    }



    document.getElementById('result').value = nameEmail;

    return false;
}

function init() {
    'use strict';
    document.getElementById('myaccount').onsubmit = empwd;
}


window.onload = init;
```

Comment: Login processes involve server-side activity, generally; it's the only way to provide any security. The login page would post the form to the server, the credentials would be validated, and then the server would redirect to some sort of home page.

Comment: So is there no way to test this? I understand what you are saying, but I can't even view it first?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question.

Comment: Without the page actually being live yet, is there a way I can see what will display when it is sent server side and back?

Comment: Well you could mock up the response page, I guess; where is the HTML going to come from if you don't have the site deployed?

Comment: Only I can see it, it is in my files only as I know this is a very bad way of doing things for security reasons. I also don't want to use window.location to achieve this. Thanks for any help.